# How to loop all components of a GtkWidget, say GtkDialog?

Tags: gtk

What's the right way to get children of a GtkDialog ?

I tried this :

```
dlgg = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new(...)
GList *children = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(dlgg))
for (GList * it = children; it; it = it->next)
{
    if (GTK_IS_BUTTON(it->data)) 
        g_print("button label %s\n", gtk_button_get_label(GTK_BUTTON(it->data)));
}
```

But no output . actually, I call gtk_dialog_run(dlgg) and found it at least has 'cancel', 'Open' button...

I tried:

```
GtkWidget* action_area = gtk_dialog_get_action_area(GTK_DIALOG(dlgg));
GList *children = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(dlgg));
```

But gcc complains :

```
error: `gtk_dialog_set_action_area' was not declared in this scope
```

And I also include `gtk/gtk.h` and other methods work well, Why?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Typo? You write that you used `gtk_dialog_get_action_area` but that gcc complains about `gtk_dialog_set_action_area` not existing (note set vs get). The former does exist and should work, the latter does indeed not exist, see https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDialog.html.

Comment: there's also the question of what are you trying to achieve: why are you trying to iterate over the child widgets of a GtkFileChooserDialog?